# How to convert a string to a java list?

Tags: java, json, string, list, gson

I have a string like so:

```
"[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]"
```

How can I turn it into List, could be list of int or list of strings:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

I tried using Gson:

```
List list = new Gson().fromJson(string, List.class);
```

It gets me:

```
[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0]
```

I could convert the double to int but I'm sure there's a better way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Gson, by default, uses `Double` for any numeric value. You need to specify that you want `Integer`

```
List<Integer> list = new Gson().fromJson(json, new TypeToken<List<Integer>>() {}.getType());
System.out.println(list);
```

prints

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

A `TypeToken` is kind of a *hack* to get the generic type so that Gson knows what to use.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Gson, you can do this:

```
String yourString = "[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]";
yourString = yourString.subString(1,yourString.length()-1) // get rid of '[' and ']'
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(yourString.split(",")));
```

Comment: ^this, but would this method be faster/less costly?

Comment: @yao It would for this specific use case.

Comment: Why so many upvotes?!?!?!  This is clearly a specific use case solution.

Comment: I just try to provide another straightforward solution, I also like Sotirios's answer more :)

Answer (score 1):

```
String s = "[1,2,3,4]";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
List<Integer> integers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
while (m.find()) {
    integers.add(Integer.parseInt(m.group()));
}
System.out.println(integers);
```